# MS Explorer not searching WebDAV virtual directory using SEARCH request type

Tags: search, iis-6, webdav

I have a MS Windows Server 2003 installed and configured on the virtual machine. WebDAV is configured too. Also I have installed and configured MS Search, it has successfully indexed needed locations. Full text search was configured as well.

I'm trying to access virtual directory from client PC(windows 8) using mapping network drive or by directly accessing it using mini-redirector.

Fiddler is catching requests from MS Explorer to the server but all request are PROPFIND. Seems like MS Explorer(using MS Search) getting metadata for content of the virtual directory and performs search on the received data.

I want to make MS Explorer to search on the content of the files too.
And I assume that client PC will use indexed data from server PC.

But using fiddler I cannot catch any SEARCH requests.

Please advise me what I might be doing wrong or what should be done additionaly(configuration/etc) to achive MS explorer search using server indexed data(full text search, etc).

Thanks in advance.